# Flutter how to create custom button border

Tags: flutter

I want to create a button like this. I think I can do this with clippath but I have no idea about it. I would be glad if you help

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Grasshopper but I don't think this is the solution

Comment: Check out this link - https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-borderradius-widget/amp/
You have to use BorderRadius.only method
Then, set topRight and bottomLeft to BorderRadius.zero and set topLeft and bottomRight to some desired value (like 5).

Comment: oooow sory @Grasshopper this is my carelessness... thank you so much for helping

Comment: Tell in the comments if that works for you.

Comment: @Grasshopper yes it worked but there is a problem. I can't place the button at the end of the frame like this, there is space. Do you have an opinion on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 90),
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              '24.00 ₴',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And it will look this way:

[image: button]